# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/ProvisionNode

Tags: java, log4j

I'm running some very old legacy code, which has worked in the past. This time, it's giving me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/ProvisionNode
```

The line that causes the error is

```
public static org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger(java.lang.String name) { /* compiled code */ }
```

in the Logger class defined by log4j. I have log4j 1.2.17 included in the code, which is the most up-to-date version according to [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j).

Has anyone else seen this error? Any idea what it could be? Thanks!!

Please note this problem has now been solved, the solution accepted below solves the problem. This is a specific issue with the `ProvisionNode` class, which is found in only certain log4j libraries. It should be left here and NOT marked as duplicate for others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: Use the version of Log4J that the code was designed to work with.

Comment: add log4j in your classpath.

Comment: There is **NO** `ProvisionNode` class in [log4j 1.2.17](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thanks everybody for the rapid responses. I'm running this code from a compiled `.jar` file, and I've included the log4j jar in there too - once again, this has run in the past (with the same version of log4j) so it's probably not a structural issue

Comment: Download [Apache logging jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachelogginglog4jjar.htm). It has the ProvisionNode class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the [Apache Logging Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachelogginglog4jjar.htm) file
2. Add the apache-logging-log4j.jar file to your classpath
3. Clean and build your project.
4. Run your project

Comment: Thanks, just about to try this - should it REPLACE the previous log4j library, or do they both need to be there?

Comment: Try replacing it first

Comment: This worked! Many thanks for your help. I added the new log4j without removing the other.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to remove `<provided>` tag from my maven dependencies, so It cannot find anything on local machine